# Unsure how to use methods in a class

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm currently trying to add users to a list in a console application. Once the user has entered all the names of people I want to run a method "GetUsers()" to display names of all users in the list. I'm not sure how to do this, but have given it a go in my code below. I would appreciate a little explanation of where I am going wrong, and how to fix this.

I know how to do this in the main program but was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this using a class.

Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        string addAnother = "y";
        while (addAnother == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name: ");
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();
            User user = new User(userName, userAge, userAddress, userPhone);
            users.Add(user);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

User class

```
class User
{


    private string _name;



    public User(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }



    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }



    public static void GetUsers()
    {
        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            //Display users
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your loop is infinite. you need to put this inside loop `addAnother = Console.ReadLine();` so loop repeats until user enters `y`. Also you need another class, for example `UserList` which has list of users property and put GetUsers method in it. currently its not possible to do it with single user class.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks, i'll fix that shortly, i'm just wondering how to call the method GetUsers() from the main program. Any ideas?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks for that, I'll give it a go. Will I be able to access the list from the UserList class though? As that what I'm having trouble with

Comment: do you really need to use a class to implement GetUsers? why not just creating method in program class and send the list over there and print items?

Comment: there is a lot of space in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Move GetUsers() method into main program class and remove static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `GetUsers()` method in your `User` class, you will have to create a static List of users in that same class with a static `AddUser()` method, like this:

```
class User
{
    private static List<User> users;

    private string _name;

    public User(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }


    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public static void AddUser(User u)
    {
        if (users == null)
            users = new List<User>();

        users.Add(u);
    }

    public static void GetUsers()
    {
        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            //Display users
        }
    }
}
```

To add a user:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name: ");
string userName = Console.ReadLine();

User user = new User(userName);
User.AddUser(user);
```

To display all users:

```
User.GetUsers();
```

Anything declared as *static* is not associated with any object, instead with the class itself. Hence when you're calling `AddUser()` or `GetUsers()` you are calling them from the `User` class, **not** the user object you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to implement `GetUsers` inside `User` class. Its not good (by design) because each user is supposed to hold information of it self not other users.

You can create another class called `UserList` to achieve what you want.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UserList userList = new UserList();

        string addAnother = "y";
        while (addAnother == "y" || addAnother == "Y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name: ");
            User user = new User(Console.ReadLine());
            userList.Add(user);
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another user? (y)");
            addAnother = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        userList.GetUsers();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Note that you can use Properties instead of `GetName` and `SetName` methods. although properties will compile to methods but its not common to use methods over properties.

Also you can override ToString method of object class. so when you want to convert User into string in order to display it this overriden method is used.

```
class User
{
    private string _name;

    public User(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name // this is the property
    {
        get { return _name; }  //  GetName
        set { _name = value; } //  SetName
    }

    public override string ToString() // this is called when you do user.ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name : {0}", Name); // return needed information.
    }
}
```

This is the UserList class which is supposed to hold all the users. so you need property of `List<User>` and you can implement GetUsers method inside it.

```
class UserList
{
    private List<User> _users;

    public UserList()
    {
        _users = new List<User>();
    }

    public void Add(User user)
    {
        Users.Add(user);
    }

    public void GetUsers()
    {
        foreach (var user in Users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }
    }

    public List<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion UserList.GetUsers() should not have the responsibility of printing users to Console. This does not make this method reusable in other contexts (for ex. write users to file). The naming of the method with this implementation is not correct either, as it writes users to console instead of giving you the user objects. I suggest User[] GetUsers() implementation where you return an array from _users collection, this way private collection stays encapsulated and the method is more reusable.

Comment: @Tony i agree.  the better name for it would be `PrintUsers`.